# Can not Create a MQTT stream with Username and Password

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, mqtt, apache-bahir

I want to create a MQTT stream which uses username and password for subscription. I am using apache-bahir for creating mqtt stream. When I used MQTTUtils.createStream() method, It only accepts ssc,brokerurl,topic, and StorageLevel as parameters. When I gave the username and password, it shows "Can not resolve symbol createStream().

```
val lines = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topic, storageLevel, clientId, username, password, cleanSession, qos, connectionTimeout, keepAliveInterval, mqttVersion)
```

https://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/2.3.0/spark-streaming-mqtt/

This page is I refereed for the implementation.

```
val sc = new SparkContext()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc,Seconds(10))
val stream = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc,"broker.mqttdashboard.com","tag_topic",StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY,"clientid","username","password")
```

Error Message is Cannot Resolve Symbol MQTTUtils.createStream()

Answer (score 0):

Try to this:

```
 val spark  = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("app")
      .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
  .option("username", username)
  .option("password", password)
  .option("topic", topic)
  .option("brokerUrl",brokerUrl )
  .load()
```

you have all the information in [Github](https://github.com/apache/bahir/blob/master/sql-streaming-mqtt/README.md)

Comment: Basic explanation would make this answer more usable for others.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaStreamingContext we can solve this problem

```
val jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc,Seconds(2))
val clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId()
val stream =  MQTTUtils.createPairedByteArrayStream(jssc,brokerUrl,topic,clientId,username,password,true)
stream.print()
jssc.start()
jssc.awaitTermination()
```